# How to set the worksheet name with Excel Interop

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, worksheet

```
 using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
 {  
      wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
      wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
      wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
      Response.Clear();
      Response.Buffer = true;
      Response.Charset = "";
      Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
      Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= EmployeeReport.xlsx");

      using (MemoryStream mymemorystream = new MemoryStream()) {
           wb.SaveAs(mymemorystream);

           mymemorystream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);

           Response.Flush();
           Response.End();   
      }
}
```

The error message I'm getting is

> Worksheet names cannot be empty.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned object of a worksheet adding operation is the worksheet itself. Change the worksheet name on that object:

```
var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
ws.Name = "my sheet name";
```

Also, because you're using a DataTable as your source for the sheet, you have to make sure the table has a name:

```
dt.TableName = "my sheet name";
```

---

**References**

- Microsoft Docs [Worksheet.Name Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.name.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: this is new error :The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Office installed, and in particular the Interop COM assemblies?